# checking if libtool supports shared libraries... no

Tags: curl, libtool

I am trying to cross compile CURL for ARM and Linux Platform. It doesn't create the Make file for Shared Library When i do through ./configure, it is providing the make file for static library only. Below two major errors are seen in the log,

**checking whether the /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.6 linker (arm-none-linux-gnueabi-ld) supports shared libraries... no
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... no

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

```
    ./configure --host=arm-none-linux-gnueabi --build=i686-linux CFLAGS='-Os' --with-ssl=/ROOT/openssl/libs --with-zlib --enable-smtp --enable-shared=yes
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

curl version:     7.42.0
  Host setup:       arm-none-linux-gnueabi
  Install prefix:   /usr/local
  Compiler:         /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc-4.6
  SSL support:      enabled (OpenSSL)
  SSH support:      no      (--with-libssh2)
  zlib support:     enabled
  GSS-API support:  no      (--with-gssapi)
  TLS-SRP support:  no      (--enable-tls-srp)
  resolver:         default (--enable-ares / --enable-threaded-resolver)
  IPv6 support:     no      (--enable-ipv6)
  Unix sockets support: enabled
  IDN support:      no      (--with-{libidn,winidn})
  Build libcurl:    Shared=no, Static=yes
  Built-in manual:  enabled
  --libcurl option: enabled (--disable-libcurl-option)
  Verbose errors:   enabled (--disable-verbose)
  SSPI support:     no      (--enable-sspi)
  ca cert bundle:   no
  ca cert path:     no
  LDAP support:     no      (--enable-ldap / --with-ldap-lib / --with-lber-lib)
  LDAPS support:    no      (--enable-ldaps)
  RTSP support:     enabled
  RTMP support:     no      (--with-librtmp)
  metalink support: no      (--with-libmetalink)
  HTTP2 support:    disabled (--with-nghttp2)
  Protocols:        DICT FILE FTP FTPS GOPHER HTTP HTTPS IMAP IMAPS POP3 POP3S RTSP SMB SMBS SMTP SMTPS TELNET TFTP

##############################
```

I am new to Linux & trying to figure out the root cause, Can any one help me what i am missing here.

Answer (score 3):

Issue was because of wrong linker path.

Export LD as /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-ld.